# rewrite part of binary file

Tags: c++, file, fwrite, fseek

I have image file with header and metainformation, image data stored after header, I want to rewrite image data, but other data around imagesection is corrupted(header) and file truncated.

How can I done it properly?

Here is the code:

```
FILE* f = _tfopen(fileName, _T("wb"));
if( f != NULL )
{
        uint64 headerSize = 8;
        char arr[2*3*3]; //w=3 h=2  RGB
        memset(arr,100,2*3*3);
        _fseeki64(f, headerSize, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(arr,sizeof(char),sizeof(arr),f);
        fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: @cHao I'm using this code from C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to change open mode from your file from `"wb"` to `"r+b"`

from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/):

`"w" write: Create an empty file for output operations. If a file with the same name already exists, its contents are discarded and the file is treated as a new empty file.`

Comment: `w+` in that same table indicates it's the wrong choice as well (ie: that the file would still be truncated).  Looks like it ought to be `r+b`.